# Is it possible to have multiple coexisting Rust installations?

Tags: settings, rust

Would it be possible to have a nightly build Rust compiler for convenience (faster build cycle, auto-update) and a dev version of Rust cloned from GitHub for experimentation purposes?

The idea is I have a binary version of Rust for my various project and a version of Rust I can hack on, without them causing havoc between each other.

If it matters, assume my OS is Ubuntu 64-bit.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The current solution is to use [rustup](https://www.rustup.rs/). Once installed, you can install multiple *toolchains*:

```
rustup install nightly
rustup install stable
rustup install 1.7
```

If you have a local build of Rust, you can *link* it as a toolchain

```
rustup toolchain link my-development /path/to/rust/code
```

You can pick a *default toolchain*

```
rustup default stable
```

Or add an *override toolchain* for a specific directory on your machine only via `rustup`

```
cd /my/cool/project
rustup override set nightly
```

Or add an override toolchain that lives with a specific directory, like a repository, via a [`rust-toolchain` file](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/overrides.html#the-toolchain-file)

```
cd /my/cool/project
echo "nightly" > rust-toolchain
```

If you want to just use a different toolchain temporarily, you can use the "plus syntax":

```
rustc +1.7 --help
cargo +nightly build
```

In other cases you can use `rustup run` to run any arbitrary command in a specific toolchain:

```
rustup run nightly any command you want here
```

See also:

- [How to execute cargo test using the nightly channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48593858/155423)

Answer (score 2):

Sure. In the development version, use the `--prefix` option to `./configure`, e.g. `--prefix=~/opt/rust-dev`, and then its installed files will be contained entirely inside that directory.

Comment: Ok, but having `make install` won't cause the two Rust compiler to jump at each others neck? Also how will testing work in presence of a possibly older `rustc`? How do I run the rust test suite on `rust-dev`?

Comment: @DanielFath, `--prefix` script defines a directory where ALL files (I mean, all files which constitute ready-to-use compiler) generated by the build process will go. No other changes in you system will be made. You shouldn't even use sudo for `make install`. Then you will have to add corresponding `bin` directory to `PATH` environment variable to call `rustc` directly, something like `export PATH="~/opt/rust-dev:$PATH"`. Then in this particular shell you will be using development version of the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Try to configure your IDE. Though I am working on Windows computer, I think the idea is similar to Ubuntu.

First, I've installed 3 versions of Rust into:

C:\Rust\64 beta MSVC 1.9
C:\Rust\64 nightly MSVC 1.10
C:\Rust\64 stable MSVC 1.8

Then I configured my IDE (in this case, IntelliJ IDEA 2016 + Rust Plug-In) to use different versions of Rust depending on build selector.

After this I can compile my code with different Rust versions just by selecting build-config from toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

You also don't need to install your development version. You could just make symlink from somewhere in your $PATH to the rustc binary that lives somewhere inside the source tree/build directory, the compiler will find its dynamically linked dependencies and it will emit binaries that know about that path too (if even dynamically linked).

Answer (score 0):

Try [envirius](https://github.com/ekalinin/envirius).

It allows you to create any number of environments with any version of the rust.

For the first time it will download the source code of the rust and will compile it.
And it will take some time. But second and subsequent attempts will takes under 10 seconds as it just will copy the binaries into the target environment.

For example:

```
➥ nv mk --rust=0.9
Creating environment: rust-0.9 ...
 * installing rust==0.9 ...
 * done (in 5 secs.)

➥ nv ls
Available environment(s):
rust-0.9

➥ nv on rust-0.9
Environment rust-0.9 activated.

(rust-0.9) ➥ rustc -v
rustc 0.9
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually when dealing with `rustup`, you're dealing with **toolchains**–a single installation of the Rust compiler. There are 3 major release channels:

- stable
- beta
- nightly

The channel can be appended with optional date and host names: `channel[-date][-host]`.

You can install multiple toolchains using `rustup`:

```
rustup toolchain install nightly
rustup toolchain install stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
```

Be careful when nightly is installed as any updates using `rustup update` will **also update stable**.

You can have different level of overrides:

```sh
# command level
rustc +beta <command>
cargo +beta <command>

# environment level
export RUSTUP_TOOLCHAIN=nightly-2019-05-22

# directory level
rustup override set stable
```

The toolchain configuration can also be version controlled using a `rust-toolchain` file, which contains just the toolchain name.

```sh
$ cat rust-toolchain
nightly-2019-05-22
```

No host name can be configured in the `rust-toolchain` file.

The override precedence is:

- An explicit toolchain, e.g. `cargo +beta`
- The `RUSTUP_TOOLCHAIN` environment variable
- A directory override, ala `rustup override set beta`
- The `rust-toolchain` file
- The default toolchain

Reference: https://github.com/rust-lang/rustup.rs#toolchain-specification