# How to execute cargo test using the nightly channel?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm trying to run my tests with nightly Rust using Windows Powershell. I run `cargo test` in the directory, and I get

```
Compiling rustcraft v0.1.0 (file:///C:/Users/Phoenix/Desktop/Rust/rustcraft)
error[E0554]: #![feature] may not be used on the stable release channel
 --> C:\Users\Phoenix\Desktop\Rust\rustcraft\src\main.rs:1:1
  |
1 | #![feature(integer_atomics)]
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0554]: #![feature] may not be used on the stable release channel
 --> C:\Users\Phoenix\Desktop\Rust\rustcraft\src\main.rs:2:1
  |
2 | #![feature(collections)]
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Obviously, I have to tell Cargo to compile it on the nightly channel, but how? I can't find any reference to specifying a channel in the help section, or any website I've found.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

The command line solution may help you to configure your IDE:

```
cargo +nightly test
```

Provided, of course, that you have the nightly channel installed. If not, perhaps install it with `rustup install nightly` (no need to switch to it, but check you're still on stable: `rustup show`).

Comment: In case anyone ran into the same thing I did, the order of arguments matters.  That is, `cargo test +nightly` does not work.

Answer (score 51):

The `+<toolchain>` functionality comes from [rustup](https://www.rustup.rs/), the Rust toolchain manager. It works for both `cargo +<toolchain>` as well as `rustc +<toolchain>`.

In addition, you can

- Use `rustup run <toolchain> <any arbitrary command goes here>`
- Change into the directory and run `rustup override set <toolchain>` to always use the nightly toolchain in that directory, since your project requires nightly features.
- Create a file called `rust-toolchain.toml` in your directory containing

  ```ini
  [toolchain]
  channel = "nightly"
  ```

  (previously `rust-toolchain` just containing the name of the toolchain required (e.g. nightly)). This has the safe effect as an [override](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/overrides.html) like above, but can be committed to source control.

See also:

- [Is it possible to have multiple coexisting Rust installations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22758779/155423)

Comment: an e.g. `rustup run nightly cargo build --target wasm32-unknown-unknown`