# Use nightly rustfmt with stable compiler in CLion

Tags: rust, clion, rustfmt

I am running into an unexpected issue when it comes to toolchains in CLion. I want to use the stable channel for the compiler while using the nightly for rustfmt. The reason is that I want to use rustfmt features that are not available in the stable version. Unfortunately CLion only picks up the currently selected toolchain without any way to override or customize this and thus has not option to select the nightly of rustfmt for formatting. Is there any workaround or option I did not notice when looking for it?

In the comment there was the suggestion that `cargo +nightly fmt` might be what I am looking for. Even though it allows to used the nightly of rustfmt it is not integrated into the flow of CLion which seems to use the currently enabled version of the entire toolchain.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to execute cargo test using the nightly channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48593858/how-to-execute-cargo-test-using-the-nightly-channel)

Comment: Not necessarily since this would be invoking the formatter manually via the command line. Of cource a `cargo +nightly fmt` would work, it's not integrated into the flow of CLions auto-formatting when saving a file.

Comment: Did you try to configure the formatter as external tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under `Clion | Preferences...`:

1. search for `formatter`
2. select `Rustfmt` on the left column
3. add `+nightly` to the `Additional arguments:` box
4. check `Use rustfmt instead of the built-in formatter`
5. click `Ok`

Now `Code | Reformat File with rustfmt` should respect `rustfmt` nightly settings.  (CLion 2022.2.4)

[image: CLion | Preferences... dialog box showing settings for nightly rustfmt on stable rustc]