# Debug Rust binary built in nightly mode

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, vscode-debugger

I would like to debug my rust source code by clicking on "Debug" in the UI (see screenshot). I need to enable the `nightly` flag for my code to work. How can I update the default debug configuration to pass the `nightly` flag? To make things more complex, I'm connected to a remote box via SSH.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Shepmasters solution from [How to execute cargo test using the nightly channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48593858/how-to-execute-cargo-test-using-the-nightly-channel) should work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the standard mechanisms to specify nightly using a toolchain [override](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/overrides.html). If your code should always use nightly, your best bet is to either:

- set a override via `rustup override set nightly` in your project's directory
- create a `rust-toolchain.toml` file with `[toolchain] channel = "nightly"`

That way *all* Cargo commands in your project will use it.