# error[E0554]: #![feature] may not be used on the stable release channel Couldn't install racer using cargo

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm trying to install racer using cargo, so I executed the command `cargo install racer` in the terminal and  it resulted in the error:

```
error[E0554]: #![feature] may not be used on the stable release channel
--> /home/rajkumar/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/scoped-tls-0.1.2/src/lib.rs:47:34
|
47 | #![cfg_attr(feature = "nightly", feature(macro_vis_matcher))]
|                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0554]: #![feature] may not be used on the stable release channel
--> /home/rajkumar/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/scoped-tls-0.1.2/src/lib.rs:48:34
|
48 | #![cfg_attr(feature = "nightly", feature(allow_internal_unstable))]
|                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0554`.
error: failed to compile `racer v2.1.10`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `/tmp/cargo-install5YWPWW`

Caused by:
Could not compile `scoped-tls`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

Below are my Rust details:

```
$rustc --version
rustc 1.30.0 (da5f414c2 2018-10-24)

> rustup --version 
rustup 1.14.0 (1e51b07cc 2018-10-04)

> cargo --version 
cargo 1.30.0 (36d96825d 2018-10-24)
```

Below is my opensuse version details:

```
> cat /usr/lib/os-release 
NAME="openSUSE Tumbleweed"
# VERSION="20181029"
ID="opensuse-tumbleweed"
ID_LIKE="opensuse suse"
VERSION_ID="20181029"
PRETTY_NAME="openSUSE Tumbleweed"
ANSI_COLOR="0;32"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:opensuse:tumbleweed:20181029"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.opensuse.org"
HOME_URL="https://www.opensuse.org/"
```

Why am I not able to install racer using cargo? Am I missing anything?

Comment: The message say, you must use nightly compiler. https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustup.rs/blob/master/README.md#working-with-nightly-rust and more info, https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/2018-edition/appendix-06-nightly-rust.html after installed you can just use `cargo +nightly build`

Answer (score 106, accepted):

As the error message states, you cannot compile that code with stable Rust. You need to install nightly Rust and then use it to compile the program:

```
rustup install nightly
cargo +nightly install racer
```

See also:

- [How to execute cargo test using the nightly channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48593858/155423)
- [Is it possible to have multiple coexisting Rust installations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22758779/155423)
- [Rocket requires a minimum version of Rust nightly, but a higher stable version is already installed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55230896/155423)

Answer (score 83):

I had the same error coming from the `thiserror` crate.
`cargo clean` fixed the problem in my case.
Since it seem that this error comes up often, try to `cargo clean` first. Maybe nightly is not mandatory.

Comment: Had the same issue with `anyhow` crate. This tip solved it.

Comment: Had the same issue with `clippy`. Solved it too, thanks

Comment: Thanks, this helped. But why does Rust end up in this situation? `cargo clean` is sort of a hammer, so wanted to understand the real reason of why this happens?

Comment: if `cargo clean` still not work, try to delete `target` folder under your project and close your IDE and then  run `cargo run` on the cmd , and open your project IDE again to check if it can compile

Answer (score 22):

This error message states, you cannot compile that code with stable Rust. You need to install nightly Rust and then use it to compile the program. You can use the following commands to run the code.

To install nightly version:
`rustup install nightly`

To set nightly version as default:
`rustup default nightly`

At anytime if you want to switch back to stable Rust:
`rustup default stable`

The nightly version is updated very frequently, so you might want to update it every week or more often. To do so, you need to run this command:
`rustup update`

I am closing this issue as it has been solved. If the problem persists, please comment and the issue will be reopened if appropriate

Answer (score 7):

I received error 0554 when trying to compile source code using the stable channel for `armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf`.

It failed because the application uses features not available in the stable channel.

The solution was to install the nightly channel with:

```
rustup install nightly
```

And then to compile with:

```
cargo +nightly build --target=armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
```

That did it for me.

Don't be tempted to follow the syntax offered when rustup installs the nightly channel, because it won't work:

```
cargo build --target=nightly-armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
```

Answer (score 3):

The command produce me a lot of errors and problems i following the below to make it work

`cargo +nightly install racer`

In my case, i run these 3 commands

```
1. rustup default nightly
2. rustup toolchain install nightly
3. rustup run nightly cargo bench
```

And simply run your program with this command:

```
cargo +nightly bench --bin youscriptname
```

Answer (score 1):

The rust error code [E0554](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error_codes/E0554.html) states that `#![feature] may not be used on the stable release channel`. To get use of a feature you must install non-stable rust release such `nightly`.

```bash
rustup install nightly
```

Once installed refer to installation as `+toolchain` - cargo CLI indicates `cargo [+toolchain] [OPTIONS] [COMMAND]`.

```bash
cargo +nightly run
cargo +nightly build
```